# Projection of a right angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, optimization, geometric-inequalities, projection

I'd appreciate your help in expressing $\delta$ in terms of $\phi$ and $\gamma$ in the following figure.  [image: Projection of a right angle].

Further, I'd appreciate any indication on what is the minimal and the maximal value of $\phi+\gamma$.

Thanks.

Comment: Is $PAOC$ supposed to be a pyramid?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli what can it be otherwise?

Comment: @KennyLau It can be what it looks like: a triangle with a very poor choice of notation.

Comment: Sassatelli. I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $PC=h$.

Thus, $AC=h\cot\phi$, $OC=h\cot\gamma$ and by Pythagoras theorem for $\Delta APO$ we obtain:
$$AO=h\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sin^2\phi}+\frac{1}{\sin^2\gamma}}.$$

Thus, by law of cosines we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{\sin^2\phi}+\frac{1}{\sin^2\gamma}=\cot^2\phi+\cot^2\gamma-2\cot\phi\cot\gamma\cos\delta$$ or
$$2=-2\cot\phi\cot\gamma\cos\delta$$ or
$$\cos\delta=-\tan\phi\tan\gamma.$$

I hope you mean to find a minimal value of $\phi+\gamma$, where $\delta=constant.$

Let $\phi+\gamma\geq90^{\circ}$.

Thus, the minimal value is $90^{\circ}$.

Now, let $\phi+\gamma<90^{\circ}$.

We'll prove that in this case $$\tan\phi\tan\gamma\leq\tan^2\frac{\phi+\gamma}{2}.$$
Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\sin\phi\sin\gamma\cos^2\frac{\phi+\gamma}{2}\leq\cos\phi\cos\gamma\sin^2\frac{\phi+\gamma}{2}$$ or
$$\sin\phi\sin\gamma(1+\cos(\phi+\gamma))\leq\cos\phi\cos\gamma(1-\cos(\phi+\gamma))$$ or
$$\cos(\phi+\gamma)\geq\cos(\phi+\gamma)\cos(\phi-\gamma),$$
which is obvious.

Id est,
$$0=\cos\delta+\tan\phi\tan\gamma\leq\tan^2\frac{\phi+\gamma}{2},$$
which gives
$$\phi+\gamma\geq2\arctan\sqrt{-\cos\delta}.$$
Since $2\arctan\sqrt{-\cos\delta}<90^{\circ}$, we got the answer:
$$2\arctan\sqrt{-\cos\delta}.$$

Comment: What is $\theta$?

Comment: This is a good answer, though it might be nice to mention that the Pythagoras is applied on $APO$. But, $\cos\delta$ is in the range of $[-1,1]$. What is the condition on $\gamma$ and $\phi$ to make the answer robust?

Comment: @Asman I proved that $\cos\delta<0$. Also I proved that for all acute angles $\phi$ and $\gamma$ we can get some $\delta$ by the formula, which I got.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Try $\phi=\gamma=50$. The expression gives $\cos\delta\approx 1.42$. There is also a maximum for $\phi+\gamma$. I actually misled you in the question. I'm sorry for that, and will edit the question.

Comment: @Asman OK, but  I said before that we can assume that $\phi+\gamma<90^{\circ}.$ From the equality, which I got follows that $\tan\phi\tan\gamma<1$. You changed your problem, but the original problem was solved.  It's not fair, I think.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg No argue about that. Just about "for all acute angles...". I'd appreciate any explanation on the origin of this assumption.

Comment: @Asman I think the fact that $\phi$ and $\gamma$ ate acute angles is given, See please your picture.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg First, I apologized for adding the maximum to the question. This is for the clarity of the discussion only. Even without this, a condition on $\delta +\gamma$ should be stated for your expression to hold. Your assumption is correct, but I'm curious about the origin of this assumption. Clearly, it is needed for the last expression, but can it be arise before or in the construction?